# How to get notification from server in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, web-services, notifications

For my iphone game i need to implement a notification service from the server.
That is suppose 5 person playing the game(online game) then if any one of them made a movement 
then that move must send to all his buddies. How can i achieve this. Is there any server programming needed. I'm not meaning the Apple push notification.

Can anybody help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think push notifications is the best way to do that. You should think about a permanent connection.

If you still want to make push notifications, the Apple doc is really clear

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction/Introduction.html

Answer (score 1):

I suggest looking into [Apple's GameKit framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/GameCenterOverview/GameCenterOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH5-SW7).